# How to measure contango?

Tags: derivatives, futures

Is there any unit of measure for the magnitude of the contango (or backwardation) for futures, so you can compare the contango of many symbols.

Comment: Could you use the *percent difference* between the futures price and the spot?

Comment: In some paper I've seen these ways: 1) $log(f_{10})-log(f_{3})$, where $f_{t}$ stands for the future value at time $t$; 2) the value of the 2nd principal component of the term structure.

Comment: See e.g. [VIX Central](http://vixcentral.com/) for an example of percentage difference, which yes, is a common numeraire.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just take something like

$$
\frac{\log{\frac{F_j}{F_i}}}{t_j - t_i} \times 365
$$

where $t_i$ denotes the expiry (or alternatively delivery) date of future $i$. The annualization is so you can compare different futures.

Comment: I've edited your post to typeset the mathematical notation with $\LaTeX$. Please make sure I got it right.